# Failed to convert "java.lang.String' to 'java.time.LocalDateTime' (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having trouble getting this little app to work in Spring Boot. Which consists of bringing all the "clients" that have been registered between 2 dates.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate

}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE registration_date >= :from AND 
registration_date <= :to", nativeQuery = true)
List<Cliente> findRegisteredClients(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

**Service:**

@Transactional
public List findRegisteredClients(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to)
throws Exception {
try {
return clientRepository.findRegisteredClients(from, to);
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
}

**Controller:**

@

```
GetMapping("/findClients/{from}/{to}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getRegisteredClients(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime from,
                                                    @PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDateTime to) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(clientService.findRegisteredClients(from, to));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("{\"message\": \"Error. Please try again later.\"}");
        }
    }
```

And these are the records that I have so far in my database (working with MySql):

- ID: 1, name: John, surname: Terry, registration_date: 2021-06-03
  19:11:16.000000
- ID: 2, name: Philip, surname: Turkey, registration_date: 2021-06-03
  19:15:16.000000

The **endpoint** that I try in Postman is the following:

http://localhost:9000/api/v1/clients/findClients/2021-06-03/2021-06-03

Running it brings me the error of the title of this question. I'm surely making a pretty serious mistake.

Clarification: I am working on the entity 'Client' with LocalDateTime because then I have to work with the hours and minutes that I get from the logs.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: A guess, `2021-06-03` is a date, note a date and time, so it’s not obvious how you intended it to be converted to `LocalDateTime`. You may have to perform that conversion explicitly. And use `LocalDate` for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string where you are storing the date using java Date parser .

String sDate1="03/06/2021";
//mind the format here

Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1);    System.out.println(sDate1+"\t"+date1);

You can refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`, which you are already linking to (thanks for doing that).

Comment: Intention here was to highlight the format, thanks for pointing out. The question here already uses java.time.